# Variable assignment bitwise or in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I ran into a code in Javascript like this:

```
is_enabled = is_enabled | true;
```

What does it intend to do? To me it seems doing nothing.

Comment: `is_enabled` would always be `1` in this case... maybe it was a weird way to convert `true` to an integer?

Comment: should be `||` instead of `|`; the default operator homogenizing assignment.

Comment: Where did you "run into" it? I doubt it was `|`, or it was probably a bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the code you are referring to is:

```
is_enabled = is_enabled || true
```

This allows the variable `is_enabled` to be defined elsewhere in the code.  So, `is_enabled`'s value is either it's previous definition, or if it has not been declared, it is `true`.

Comment: Thanks, I guess that's just a typo.